# Makefile from Cmake is not putting actual compilers rather it puts 'ftn' which is used as a variable for CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER

Tags: makefile, cmake, fortran, hpc

I have been trying to compile a large Fortran code with many files in it on a HPC with the use of CMake. CMake properly configures and generates a Makefile. While Making, I get an error saying `'/bin/sh: ftn: command not found'`. The Makefile tries to compile the code like this->

```
ftn  -o CMakeFiles/s3d.x.dir/modules/param_m.f90.o
```

When I compile it on my personal system or another HPC, it goes like->

```
mpif90  -o CMakeFiles/s3d.x.dir/modules/param_m.f90.o
```

I don't know why CMake is not able to put actual compilers in place of 'ftn'.
I would really appreciate if any suggestions come up.

Comment: ftn is the Cray Fortran compiler*. It is probably set in your CMakeLists.txt.
If it is not found, you probably need to load a module I guess.

*(or rather the driver, that invokes the actual Fortran compiler)

Comment: Sorry for replying late. It is set in the CMakeLists.txt as 'SET(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_INIT mpif90 ftn pgf95)'. Still, I face the same issue.

Comment: What is `CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_INIT` for? It must be used in your CMakeLists.txt, as it is not a default CMake variable. Are you sure the system you are using is correctly identified in your cmake environment? Does the system supply the Cray compiler?

Maybe you could provide us with a little bit more info other than "compiler not found" and the setting of an, to us, unknown variable?